# knp menu bundle - how to add tags to a tag?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.2, knpmenubundle

How to add tags to (a) tag ?
I can add to a `->setLinkAttribute('class', 'fa fa-edit')` but this does not solve my problem.
If I add `->setLabel('<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Forms')` It show my tags element as well.
I would like to achieve like below:

```
<ul>
     <li>
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>  <--here
        Forms
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> <--here
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your need to adapt your twig template which renders the different blocks. You can find the default template in  `vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views/knp_menu.html.twig`, but I guess you are configuring a custom template, so please add the information from your `app/config/config.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solustion.

I changed:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('InfAccountBundle:Builder:Menu') }}
```

to:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('InfAccountBundle:Builder:Menu', {'allow_safe_labels': true}) | raw }}
```

and added extra to label:

```
$menu->addChild('Baza', array('uri' => '#','childrenAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'nav child_menu',
            )))->setLabel('<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Baza<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>')->setExtra('safe_label',true);
```